# DatePicker disable national days + 48h + weekend

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I know, the title isn't really specific, but I have a problem with `DatePicker`. I try to disable the national days, weekend and 48 hours after today. For the moment I did this :

- Hide today + 48hours, I use `minDate: 3`
- Hide weekend
- Hide national days, they are saved in an array
- Hide (today + 48h) + weekend (5 days to disable), code in `beforeShow` attribute

My code look like this for the moment :

```
function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) {
    var dateTime = new Date();
    var dayOfWeek = dateTime.getDay();
    var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);

    if (noWeekend[0]) {
        natDays = [
            [1, 1, 'au'], [5, 1, 'ar'], [5, 8, 'ar'], [7, 14, 'us'], [8, 15, 'id'], [11, 1, 'lb'], [11, 11, 'lb'], [12, 25, 'ke']
        ];

        for (i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++) {
            if (date.getMonth() == natDays[i][0] - 1 && date.getDate() == natDays[i][1]) {
                return [false, ''];
            }
        }
        return [true, ''];
    } else {
        return noWeekend;
    }
}

function addDatePicker(pSelname)
{
    $(pSelname).datepicker({
        stepMonths: 1,
        firstDay: 1,
        regional:'fr',
        dayNamesShort: ['Dim', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mer', 'Jeu', 'Ven', 'Sam'],
        dayNamesMin:  ['Dim', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mer', 'Jeu', 'Ven', 'Sam'],
        dayNames: ['Dimanche', 'Lundi', 'Mardi', 'Mercredi', 'Jeudi', 'Vendredi', 'Samedi'],
        monthNames: ['Janvier','Fevrier','Mars','Avril','Mai','Juin','Juillet','Aout','Septembre','Octobre','Novembre','Décembre'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mai','Avr','Mai','Juin','Juil','Aou','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'],
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,
        minDate: 3,
        beforeShow : function() {
            var dateTime = new Date();
            var dayOfWeek = dateTime.getDay();
            if(dayOfWeek == 4 || dayOfWeek == 5) {
                $(this).datepicker( "option", "minDate", "5" );
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So, I don't know how to handle the case : (today + 48hours) + weekend + national day in the week. I wrote several cases that I need to reproduce on the `DatePicker` :

- If the current day is **monday 14 September**, and if there is a national day (*2015-09-14 or 2015-09-15 or 2015-09-16 or 2015-09-17*), the next day selectable will be friday 2015-09-18. 

  ((today + 48h) + 1 national day = 4 days disable)
- If the current day is **Thuesday 15 September**, and if there is a national day (*2015-09-15 or 2015-09-16 or 2015-09-17 or 2015-09-18*), the next day selectable will be monday 2015-09-21. 

  ((today + 48h) + 1 national day + weekend = 6 days disable)
- If the current day is **Wednesday 16 September**, and if there is a national day (*2015-09-16 or 2015-09-17 or 2015-09-18 or 2015-09-21*), the next day selectable will be Thuesday 2015-09-22.

  ((today + 48h) + 1 national day + weekend = 6 days disable)
- If the current day is **Thursday 17 September**, and if there is a national day (*2015-09-17 or 2015-09-18 or 2015-09-21 or 2015-09-22*), the next day selectable will be wednesday 2015-09-23.

  ((today + 48h) + 1 national day + weekend = 6 days disable)
- If the current day is **friday 18 September**, and if there is a national day (*2015-09-18 or 2015-09-21 or 2015-09-22 or 2015-09-23*), the next day selectable will be thursday 2015-09-24.

  ((today + 48h) + 1 national day + weekend = 6 days disable)

I don't count if there is a national days in the weekend.

The function `noWeekendsOrHolidays` is executed for each day in the month, so I need to check day by day if there is a national day.

[**JS FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/5zmv2g7c/)

So my first question is : This is really possible to do? Which algorithm can I make to resolve that problem?

Thanks

Comment: can you provide a fiddle, that will be easy for us to play around.

Comment: I created a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5zmv2g7c/)

Answer (score 1):

> So, I don't know how to handle the case : (today + 48hours) + weekend
>   + national day in the week.
>
> So my first question is : This is really possible to do ?

Yes.

> Which algorithme can i make to resolve that problem ?

Break down your problem into smaller pieces. Here is a crude example:

1. Weekend(s):

You don't need to do anything extra as the jQuery UI Datepicker will do it for you. You only call the `noWeekends` method with the selected date:

```
jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends(selDate)
```

2. National Days:

You can have an array containing the days, like this:

```
var nationalDays = ['2015-09-17', '2015-09-21', '2015-09-28'];
```

Next, create a function which will check if a particular day exists in that array. Something like this:

```
function chkNationalDays(selectedDate) {
    var retVal = [true, '', ''];
    nationalDays.forEach(function(dt) {
        var today = new Date(dt); 
        if (isEqual(selectedDate, today)) {
            retVal = [false, '', '']; return;
        }
    });
    return retVal;
};
```

Remember that the `beforeShowDay` expects an array of three values (0) a boolean specifying if the current date needs to be disabled (1) a css class for styling that date, and (2) a text to show in the tooltip.

3. Today and next 48 hours i.e. Today and next two days:

Create another function to check this. Something like:

```
function chkNext2Days(selectedDate) {
    var today = new Date(); 
    if (isEqual(selectedDate, today)) return [false, '', ''];
    today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
    if (isEqual(selectedDate, today)) return [false, '', ''];
    today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
    if (isEqual(selectedDate, today)) return [false, '', '']; 
    return [true, '', ''];
}
```

And return the array which `beforeShowDay` expects.

4. Combine all of the cases:

Now combine all of the cases together to check if any returns a false for the first element of the returned arrays. Very simply but crudely, it looks like this:

```
function noWeekendsOrHolidays(selDate) {
    var noWeekend = jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends(selDate), 
        noNationalDays = chkNationalDays(selDate),
        noNext2Days = chkNext2Days(selDate),
        retVal = true;
    if (noWeekend[0]) {
        if (noNationalDays[0]) {
            return noNext2Days;
        } else {
            return noNationalDays;
        }
    } else  {
        return noWeekend;
    }
};
```

5. Finally, set the callback on `beforeShowDay`.

This is simple:

```
$("#dateInput").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays, 
    ...
});
```

Here is a working demo, with all that code:

**Snippet**:

```js
var nationalDays = ['2015-09-17', '2015-09-21', '2015-09-28'];

$("#dt1").datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
    beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays
});

function noWeekendsOrHolidays(selDate) {
    var noWeekend = jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends(selDate), 
        noNationalDays = chkNationalDays(selDate),
        noNext2Days = chkNext2Days(selDate),
        retVal = true;
    if (noWeekend[0]) {
        if (noNationalDays[0]) {
            return noNext2Days;
        } else {
            return noNationalDays;
        }
    } else  {
        return noWeekend;
    }
};

function chkNext2Days(selectedDate) {
    var today = new Date(); 
    if (isEqual(selectedDate, today)) return [false, '', ''];
    today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
    if (isEqual(selectedDate, today)) return [false, '', ''];
    today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
    if (isEqual(selectedDate, today)) return [false, '', '']; 
    return [true, '', ''];
}

function chkNationalDays(selectedDate) {
    var retVal = [true, '', ''];
 nationalDays.forEach(function(dt) {
  var today = new Date(dt); 
        if (isEqual(selectedDate, today)) {
            retVal = [false, '', '']; return;
        }
 });
 return retVal;
};

function isEqual(srcDate, tarDate) {
    if ((srcDate.getDate() == tarDate.getDate()) &&
        (srcDate.getMonth() == tarDate.getMonth()) &&
        (srcDate.getFullYear() == tarDate.getFullYear())) {
        return true;
    } else { return false; }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
Date: <input id="dt1" />
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ug5xx4t5/1/

Comment: Thanks for your answer Abhitalks but doesn't work for my case. I changed the national days like this `var nationalDays = ['2015-09-24'];` the next day selectable will be monday 28 september, i need to disable friday 25 september. With your code I can select Friday. I need to disable `Today + 48hours + the national days = 4days` the weekend will be automatically disable and the next day will be monday.

Comment: @Remi: I am sorry if I am unable to clearly understand. Your current date is 21-Sep. 24-Sep is national day. So 21, 22, 23, and 24 will be disabled. 25-Sep is not falling in any of the conditions and hence is enabled. Do you want to also disable any dates which fall within the period of today and last disabled date?

Comment: I edited my post to add all cases. Day by day and if there is a national days in the next 4 days + weekend.